# Error #VALUE! when calculate with result of hlookup

Tags: excel-formula

This first formula, i used HLOOKUP to fill data for `column J` OK
`=HLOOKUP(LEFT(C6,1),$E$18:$H$19,2,0)`

A second formula, i would like to fill data for `column K` but error `#VALUE!`

`=((G6/26)*H6*J6)+((G6/26)*I6)`

[Description image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaC86.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the length (e.g. `=LEN(E19)` of E19:H19? Each one individually.

Comment: @Jeeped HLOOKUP was good. There is no problem

Comment: That isn't close to what I asked. I'm concerned about non-printable characters changing the numbers into text-that-look-like-numbers and producing #VALUE! in a maths operation. It's impossible to tell from your image because you've rewritten all of the default cell alignments so the LEN of each 'number' must be examined.

Comment: Cause: the result of the HLOOKUP function is a `text type`. Do you know that the function converts it to a `numberic`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a text type. `="1"+1` is the same as `=1+1`. Excel's overhead takes care of the conversion **as long as there are no addition text characters attached**. `="1"&CHAR(10)+1` returns #VALUE!

Comment: Still waiting to have my original request for LEN fulfilled.

Comment: @Jeeped About LEN : [Image result](https://imgur.com/a/SniIMRJ)

Comment: Because I understand the reason, now i will do it. Thank you for support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel's overhead can take care of text-that-look-like-a-number to true number conversion 'on the fly'. All you have to do is stick the text in a maths operation and the conversion is automatic.

```
="1"+1           'result is 2
=1+1             'result is 2
```

However, if there are extra characters attached to the text-that-look-like-a-number, Excel cannot perform the conversion and throws a #VALUE! error.

```
="1"&char(10)+1   'result is #VALUE!
```

The easiest way to check for non-printing¹ (invisible) characters like line feeds or CHAR(0) atoms is to check the length with the LEN(...) function. If the length is greater than what we can see there is likely non-printing characters attached.

For your data,

[image]

Not only is the 17 left-aligned (the default for Text), the LEN function shows that it is 3 characters wide, not the 2 characters wide that we can see.

Go back to the original value where HLOOKUP retrieved its lookup and select the cell and tap F2. Using the arraow keys will show where the rogue character is.

Delete the rogue character and your formula should resolve properly.

---

¹ <sub>Typical non-printing characters are line feeds (Chr(10)) and carriage returns (Chr(13), non-breaking spaces (Chr(160), atom delimiters like Chr(0) or zero-width spaces (Crw(8203). Text-that-look-like-a-number that has rogue characters attached is very common from data imported of copied from web sources.</sub>